# NSFetchResultController: Fill TableView with fetched entity and its related entity

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have 2 entities. One describes the Section of the TableView (A Month its name, etc.) This entity is related with a one to many relationship to another entity which should describe the rows of the TableView.

I'm a bit confused how to get those entites by an NSFetchedResultController. As far as I now I can only fetch one relationship at the time. So which one should I get to fill the table properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `NSFetchedResultsController`, you fetch the objects you want to display in the table view.

To get sections, you use `NSFetchedResultsController`'s `sectionNameKeyPath` property to indicate how to find a section name from one of the fetched objects. This key path is something you could pass to one of the fetched objects via `valueForKeyPath:` to get the section name. In your case it would require traversing a relationship back to the month entity (or whatever it really is) to get its name. For example if the relationship is called `month` and the Month entity has a `name` attribute, you would pass something like `@"month.name"` as the `sectionNameKeyPath` argument when you create the fetched results controller.

Comment: Not sure if I get it. My entites are a Month entity and an Entry entity.
The Month entity relates to the Entry entity, which should fill the rows of the TableView. The Month entity should fill the section header.

Should I change my object model or can I work with this like I intend to do...?

Comment: Does your Entry entity have a relationship back to Month? If not, it really, really should. If it **does** have a relationship back to Month, use that relationship name as part of the key path.

Comment: It has a back relationship. So I should literally fetch the Entry Entity? But then I'm not sure how to sort the entity into sections. Okay can I do it with the sectionNamekEyPath?

Comment: Yes, like I said, you should fetch the objects that you want to display in the table. `NSFetchedResultsController` will deal with figuring out what sections you need if you tell it what key path to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the excellent Sensible TableView framework to automatically fetch the Core Data objects and display them in a table view. The framework will also detect if the entities have any relationships and will automatically manage the detail view controllers between them.